# Razer Blade Stealth Trackpad jumping all over the place in 17.10

Tags: mouse, touchpad, 17.10, cursor

I thought this issue would be fixed in the final release but it wasn't, it was existent in the beta too. I am not sure if this exists in 16.10 as well, but in 16.04 it did not. My laptop is an I2C track pad if that helps.

Not really experienced too much with Ubuntu, used it a bit in the past on this laptop but needed to reinstall instead of Windows recently since the Fall Creators Update screwed my touch pad, doesn't work unless the laptop is plugged in and Razer STILL hasn't put out a fix in Razer fashion.

Now I go to install Ubuntu, but this also has track pad issues.

I understand that people need logs in order to diagnose something, but I don't know where to start at all and Googling the solution to this issue has left me here. Getting frustrating seeing people say "I fixed it" without listing an actual solution.

Its not a big jump, but enough to be very annoying. For example, my mouse cursor will be going towards the back icon in FireFox, and then suddenly will skip just over the back icon.

The trackpad is also Synaptics if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem using the solution outlined in this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/987271

In my case, I used the following for the hwdb file:

```
libinput:name:Synaptics TM2438-005:dmi:*svnRazer:*:pvr6.06*
 LIBINPUT_MODEL_LENOVO_X230=1
```

Hope this helps solve your issue!

Comment: Will try this when I get home, much appreciated. I have been looking for a solution for months now.

Comment: @ZVNexus, I'm having a similar issue on Razer Blade Stealth (2017) and Ubuntu 18. What was the full solution in your case?

Comment: @AlexanderF. https://github.com/rolandguelle/razer-blade-stealth-linux