# Choppy cursor when using touchpad

Tags: 16.04, mouse, touchpad, cursor

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 on a laptop with an ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad. The cursor movement is really choppy when I use the touchpad. There is no problem at all when I use a mouse.

I have tried to solve the problem by altering the parameters Device Accel Profile, Device Accel Constant Deceleration, Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration and Device Accel Velocity Scaling -but to no avail.

What else could I try?

Thanks

Ips

Comment: I do have same issue here. 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/983419/touchpad-makes-mouse-go-in-a-grid-like-pattern-external-mouse-doesnt

I tried a bounty but had no luck for my problem

Comment: Issue is resolved by updating libinput to the latest version, that came with ubuntu 18.04 :) Check out my thread for more. @Ips